# what to do when getting the response yt:too_many_calls?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am trying to update viewcount, on all the rows on my table, but after it hits row 200 or so i start getting the response, "yt:too_many_calls", what can i do to fix this problem , this is my code that's running for each row in the table. i have tired almost everything .

```
<?php
    class youtube {
        public $channel;
        //Json for user
        public $data = null;
        public $viewCount;
        public function __construct () {
            $channel = $this->channel;
            $this->data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $channel . '?v=2&alt=json&key=MY_DEV_KEY');
            $this->data = json_decode($this->data, true);
            $this->viewCount = $this->data['entry']['yt$statistics']['totalUploadViews'];
            return $this;
        }
    }
?>
```

i have also tired adding this but have got no luck

```
   if($this->data = 'yt:too_many_calls')
 {

    $timeMain = pow(2, $error_count);
    $timeSec = rand(1000000, 1000000000);
    time_nanosleep($timeMain, $timeSec);

 }
```

And this is how my code loops per row

```
    $query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM channels LIMIT 400");     
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS , 'youtube');
```

Comment: That means you're being rate limited. You need to slow down your program instead, or try and fetch more data at once per request.

Comment: Come on, the error message even tells you you're hitting a rate limit. Save the retrieved info on your side and refresh it from Youtube only once a day or so. (And while you're at it, make sure you don't query the same user's feed multiple times, and add a delay between API calls.)

Answer (score 0):

"too many calls", then check the API console. Maybe at your daily limit, as there is also "too many recent calls".
You need to set a longer time to sleep.

```
sleep(600); // sleep for 10 minutes.
```

From a YT blog:

In the unlikely event that you do get flagged for excessive API requests, you'll receive an HTTP response with a code of 403 and a response body that includes

```
<errors><error><domain>yt:quota</domain><code>too_many_recent_calls</code></error></errors>
```

It's up to your code to detect this error and take appropriate action. As a best practice, we recommend stopping all API calls from your application for 10 minutes after receiving such an error in order to "reset" your quota. When you resume making API calls, you should scale back on the frequency of your requests. As a rule, API requests that do not originate from user interaction – requests made one right after another as part of a background synchronization or bulk import process, for instance – are more likely to trigger quota violations, so they should be avoided.

Ref.: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html

Update: 
First, i don't use PDO. However, since the plan is to add waiting time between calls, i think you should fetch the data from the Database into an array first, before looping thru the YouTube requests. This way you can disconnect from it sooner. Something like:

```
    // pseudo code, to be changed.
 1) Save channel ID's from database into an array: $channelArray = Array();
 2) Loop thru this array, making a YouTube API request for each row.
 3) Set a limit for repeating the SAME request AGAIN: $maxLoopCount = 3;
 4) REPEAT "only for a quota error" AND "only for a limited consecutive times":
    FOREACH ($channelArray as $entry)
      { - INIT: $sameRequestLoopCounter = 0;
        - DO {
               - Make the YouTube API request for $entry[channelId];
               - $sameRequestLoopCounter++;
               - Check the response after each call:
                      {
                       - $responseText = ?;
                       - $errorMessage = ?; 
                       - Only if there is a quota error in the response data OR error message, then
                              { Wait 10 minutes. And then do the same API call again.}
                                With some timing, the wait time could be changed.
                          // Does Response OR Error message contains string "too_many_recent_calls": TRUE or FALSE:
                       - $check1 = strpos($responseText,"too_many_recent_calls");
                       - $check2 = strpos($errorMessage,"too_many_recent_calls");
                       - if ( ($check1 == 0) AND ($check2 == 0) )
                            $quotaError = FALSE;
                         else 
                            $quotaError = TRUE;
                        - if (other kind of error)
                             {
                              print $errorMessage;
                              BREAK 2;  // quit loops
                             }
                      }
               - if ($quotaError)
                   {
                     print "Waiting some time.";
                     sleep (600);
                   }
              }
                WHILE  ( ($sameRequestLoopCounter < $maxLoopCount) AND $quotaError );
        - Use the API response data for something;
     }
```

Comment: Can you please leave an example, on how i would do this? because i don't think i am doing it right. My code is provided above. Thank you!

Comment: @user3697198 Is it not a class definition ? Your code does not show, how you loop thru your calls.

Comment: @user3697198 I think those 2 lines are an init, but not a loop. Guess your loop starts just after that. Anyway, i updated my answer with a pseudo code example.

Comment: @user3697198 I think that, while fetching from the database and doing the api request in the object creation, you should also do the error checking and sleep and repeated request in the code of your class.